# Unable to make navbar horizontal

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I'm having trouble making the navbar appear across the page horizontally rather than vertically. After trying a number of different things, I think the problem revolves around the the ul class. But I just can't seem to crack the issue.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/static/kkapital.png" align="left"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, which version are you using?

Comment: If you check [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/) you might want to add a `nav-item` class to your `li` elements (depending on the version as James asks)?

Comment: I'm currently using 4.1.3

Comment: Have you tried adding `nav-item` and `nav-link` to your `li` and `a` elements, as shown in the examples in the page I linked to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few changes that needs to be done. If you check the example here you can see your code and a working sample just underneath.

The main difference is the `navbar-expand` class which makes the items fan out horizontally instead of vertically. I added a background color with `bg-light` but that is optional. Another thing is to add `nav-item` and `nav-link` to your menu items; this is mostly for styling the items with spacing, hover color and so on, but it structures your code so you can customize your navbar easier later.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```